# mongodb php creating counter for blog posts

Tags: php, mongodb

It should be general problem, but I am new to mongodb and php, so please bear with me :-).

I am creating blogpost site and intended to provided unique blogId for each blog and user can access http://www.sitename.com/blogID.

I am storing counter (as an integer) in mongodb and increment it when someone posts his/her blog :

```
$collection = $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'blogCount');;     
$object = $collection->findOne();
$count = $object['count'];
$id = $object['_id'];
$collection->update(array('_id'=>$id),array('$inc' => array("count" => 1)));
$object = $collection->findOne();
$count = $object['count'];
```

It works fine till now but what if more than one user'll try to post blog at same time, it might provide same $count to more than one user.

How can I eliminate this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you want to create a unique ID and make sure that it is not reused, even if there is concurrent access to the database.

In MongoDB, you do this using the findAndModify() command.  See here for a recipe on how to do this with MongoDB:

- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

See here for more information about findAndModify():

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822181/1408889